# Where does a Swift IOS app instantiate the View and ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to IOS App development, but I'm taking the hard road to learning it, I'm trying to avoid using interface builder.

So I'm trying to understand the flow of execution. I see that the AppDelegate has an `@UIApplicationMain` declaration, which, according to Apple's documentation, eliminates the need for a `main.swift` file. This main method would instantiate the application and application delegate.

The single view template has also created a ViewController class for me, and a Main.storyboard file. So where is the code that instantiates the ViewController and the whole view hierarchy?

If I wanted to work without interface builder, where would I instantiate a UiView? Or do I have to initialize an UIWindow? I see an UIWindow field in my app delegate class that I don't see used anywhere.

Comment: Why don't you want to use IB?

Comment: There's a part of the original question that has not really been answered: where is the code that instantiates the ViewController when one is working with a Storyboard? If ViewController is a class, one would expect to see 'let vc = ViewController()' somewhere. This seems to be a hidden part of the process when working with a Storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid Interface Builder/Storyboards, you can. You will need to Instantiate your view controller in the app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. You will then set the newly instantiated view controller as the windows root view controller.

Example:

```
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow!

func application(application: UIApplication, 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) //allocate window

let vc = ViewController() //initialize view controller
window.rootViewController = vc

window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
return true
}
```

Then in your ViewController.swift `viewDidLoad` instatiate a button or label and place it as a subview on the VC .view property to make sure it works.